# change to directory of batch script output

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting

I would like to change directory to the output of the below command.

This is pretty easy with Linux, is there way to do this with batch scripts.

```
     wmic share get path | findstr /i "test" | cd %????????????
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic share get path ^| findstr /i "test" ') do cd "%%a"
```

should get you there, I believe.

Comment: Magoo, You sir are fantastic, my Windows scripting is terrible, i would of been here for days. THANKS